# Fill a percentage of matrix with specific values with no loop

Tags: r, vector

I am new to R, and I am trying to fill 60% of a vector with character 'Y' and the remaining 40% with the character 'R'.
How could this be done?

Comment: If you're going to down vote me, would you like to tell me what I can improve on please?

Comment: show me example of input and expected output please.

Comment: array = c(1:100)
#set 60% of array to the value 'Y' and 40% to the value 'R'
# array should look like this : ['R', 'R', ..., 'Y', 'Y']

Comment: I don't know if you can do this without a for loop, which is why I am asking if anyone knows if such a syntax is available

Comment: Do you want to fill it at random or will `a <- c(rep('R', 60), rep('Y', 40))` do it? As for the downvote, please *do read* file `R-intro.pdf` that comes with your installation of R.

Answer (score 2):

As Rui Barradas said, you can fill using

```
a <- c(rep('R', 60), rep('Y', 40))
```

If you want it randomized, you can then sample it.

```
a <- sample(a)
```